# Magento 1.9.0.1 Error, then Not Valid Template File

Tags: magento, templates, magento-1.9.1

When going to the Sales/Orders and viewing an order, the Information tab (default) is blank.  View: [screenshot](http://crabcountry.web14.matice.com/custom/blanksalesorder.png)

[image]

Checked the log and saw this error:

```
Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 2: parser error : XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document  in ...wwwroot\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout\Update.php on line 450
Warning: simplexml_load_string(): &lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot;?&gt;  in ...wwwroot\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout\Update.php on line 450
Warning: simplexml_load_string():      ^  in ...wwwroot\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout\Update.php on line 450
```

Was unsure of how to handle so I cleared the var/cache and var/session, turned off the compiler and enabled errors.

That error is gone but this error now appears in the log (and the problem still exists):

```
CRIT (2): Not valid template file:adminhtml\base\default\template\aitcommonfiles/design--adminhtml--default--default--template--sales--order--view--tab--info.phtml
```

The file is there and seems fine - it wasn't customized.

Could someone point me in the right direction to troubleshoot and fix?

Comment: We posted a great debugging tutorial here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store

Comment: Kevin simplexml problems usually relate to a typo in your XML config files. Can you validate the config XML files?

Comment: Mihai - By my count there are 72 config.xml files.  There are only 3 that have a different date than the original install and all seems fine with them.  Any pointers as to what file I should be looking for?

Comment: Fabian - I went through the tutorial and nothing pops out:
- set enabled errors (had already done)
- enabled developer mode (no change)
- permissions checked (Windows machine connecting as enterprise admin)
- renamed themes (no change)
- renamed local and community code (no change)
- did file compare with fresh download of Magento, no differences with exception of added lines to index.php to turn on debug.